# Grouping rows by a certain condition from one column

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, It's my first post so i will try my best to explain the problem as simply as possible. I have a sheet where data from all articles bought from suppliers is stored. From column A to G, the data is "Ref Article", "Name","Supplier","Description","Unitary Cost", "Quantity", "Total Cost(Qt*U.cost). 
I would like to group the rows of each supplier in a separate sheet for each one(+50 different Supp).

Separately I need that when inside a group of articles of a supplier are items with the same "Ref Article" or the same "Name",(there are articles without "ref Article" or "Name") the macro sum the quantity and the total to finally show only one row for each type of article with all the quantities and total for that articles.

I'm not asking for the macro done, but if somebody can provide me the functions i could try to solve the problem. I don't know which function use to filter the groups, and i tried to make loops that creates me the new sheets and a counter for each one of the articles but was a disaster.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of sample data as well as the code you created.
It will be easier to give you advice from what you are doing than from 0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's make some hypotheses:

- You already have all your sheets for your suppliers
- These suppliers sheets have the same name than what you can find in your data sheet

What you can do is:

```
Dim sheetSupplier As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, last_used_row_supplier As Integer

With Sheets("Data") 'the sheet where all your data is located

    For i = 2 To 100 'please change according to the correct start and end
    
        supplier_sheet = .Cells(i, 3) 'gives the supplier name for each row, hence sheet name
        Set sheetSupplier = Sheets(supplier_sheet)
        next_row_supplier = sheetSupplier.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1 'gives row to use next
        
        'Now you can copy your data by using cells = cells
        
        sheetSupplier.Cells(next_row_supplier , 1) = .Cells(i, 1) 'column 1 in supply sheet = column 1 in data sheet
        sheetSupplier.Cells(next_row_supplier , 2) = .Cells(i, 5) 'column 2 in supply sheet = column 5 in data sheet
        '... and so on ...
    
    Next

End With
```

Regarding the sum per article, you can simply use a conditional sum (like the SUMIF Excel function).